# win32/stdlib detecting only half the number of logical cores in C/C++ under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, cpu-cores

I have a math C++ program compiled with mingw-w64, which detects the number of logical cores in the system for starting the optimal number of working threads.

It works well on all machines I have tested so far, but one user is reporting that only 20 threads are started, while he has a 2-Xeon machine with 10 hyperthreaded cores each, for a total of 40 logical processors.

The Windows 2012 Server task manager reports: 2 sockets, 20 cores, 40 logical processors (I have the screenshot). The multiple CPU load chart has 40 graphs (I also have the screenshot)

But, I always detect only 20 logical processors, using either of the three following methods:

- `GetSystemInfo()` from Win32 C API
- `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` from C++11 stdlib
- `QThread::idealThreadCount()` from Qt 5.4

And anyway, it is likely that the two latter are implemented using the first one.

How can I properly detect the actual number of logical cores?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `GetLogicalProcessorInformation()` return?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant : Thanks for the link, but it says "On systems with 64 or fewer processors, existing applications will operate correctly without modification". So it seems not related to this problem

Comment: It is up to the system designer how to organize the cores.  A machine like this has a Numa architecture, splitting the cores into two groups is not entirely illogical.  The only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: I concur with Hans, the documentation isn't always 100% accurate.  Also you might want to double-check that the process is running in 64-bit mode, just to be sure.

Comment: I will definitely have a look into this. However, it seems that even if I properly detect the two processor groups, my process will only run in one even if I create 40 threads. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks, this was due to the machine which was set to use two processing groups. Do you want to write a detailed answer on this topic, or should I?